# Does mysqli_get_client_stats send requests to sql server

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysqlnd

This method is supplied since mysqlnd: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysqli-get-client-stats.php

It allows to get a lot of statistics (byte_received...)

Are these information collected at query time (while sending the sql request, maybe they are simply part of the result returned by MySQL server) or are these collected with another request call to the mysql server ?

I try to evaluate the kind of overhead I'll have by calling this stat function really frequently in our dev environment

Comment: I suggest you try it and evaluate the overhead :)

Comment: [From the description in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.stats.php) I would suggest that these stats are held in the `mysqlind` driver. So quite possibly there is actually no interaction with the database involved in a clal to this function